# How to import component in react native past two folders?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whenever I try to import a component that is two or more folders back I get an issue. Using ../Folder works fine, but if I try to use .../Folder I get a module error. How do I get through the directory?

Comment: Can you show us your project directory please?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `../..` to go up two directories.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to import for example index.css,
case 1: Same folder
import './index.css';

case 2: one dir up
import '../index.css';

case 3: two dir up
import '../..index.css';

Comment: Missing additional '/'. It's
```'../../index.css'```

Answer (score 3):

Simply go back by one level using "../" 
Now for 2 levels and so on append "../"

This is for 2 level back.

../../YOUR_PATH/FILE_NAME

example:

/src/component/form/file1.js

If above file need to reach another file in dir parallel to 'component' as in above path i.e.  '/src/assets/file.css' so path in file1.js would be as following:

../../assets/file.css