# React Native import .js file from different root directory

Tags: javascript, react-native, import

Hello I tried to import style.js file (on bottom) into HistoryTab.js that refer on an image that I attached.
I already tried

```
import Styles from "_styles";
```

or

```
import Styles from "../styles";
```

but it's a false solution because the "_styles" module was not found.
May I know the right solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance
[Here my file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB9SC.png)

Comment: Show the code that's trying to import your file. Also tell us the error that you get.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, i find out the correct solution.
refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642708/how-to-import-component-in-react-native-past-two-folders/44642796) where the solution is

```
import Styles from "../../styles"
```